# Unable to restore WhatsApp chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have followed all the possible ways to restore my WhatsApp chat, but I'm unable to do so.

I uninstalled and reinstalled WhatsApp three times and had my WhatsApp data in my SD card even after I moved it to my new phone. I'm unable to get my data back. I'm even unable to rename the backup files.

How do I restore the chats?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp encrypted database needs same phone number to be decrypted.

- Back up your chats on your old phone.
      Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat settings > Back up chats.
- Transfer your External microSD card to your new phone if your WhatsApp/Database folder is located in your external microSD card.
      Please see below if your WhatsApp folder is located in your device's internal memory.
- Install WhatsApp on your new phone.
- **You must have the same phone number in WhatsApp that you had when you backed up your chats.**
- Click Restore when prompted to restore your message history.

Note: You cannot restore chat history from any other phone type to Android, or from Android to another phone type.

Related discussion: [I'm getting a new Android. How do I move my chat history over?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20902622)